# ¿Cómo utilizar inner join con tres tablas con mismo identificador?

Tags: mysql

tengo las siguientes tablas que deseo se muestren todos los datos de la tabla ot_ploteo y la tabla ot_servicio_tecnico, pero con el codigo que he intentado no obtengo el resultado, y si los obtengo se duplican, ayuda por favor.

```
SELECT
* 
FROM
    ((
            ot_servicio_tecnico otst
            INNER JOIN cliente cst ON cst.ID_Cliente = cst.ID_Cliente
            INNER JOIN tipo_documento tdst ON tdst.ID_Documento = otst.ID_Documento 
            )
        INNER JOIN ot_ploteo otp
        INNER JOIN cliente cp ON cp.ID_Cliente = cp.ID_Cliente
    INNER JOIN tipo_documento tdp ON tdp.ID_Documento = otp.ID_Documento 
    )
```

**Estas son mis tablas donde quiero hacer la consulta**
[image: Imagen de las tablas a consultar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres mostrar todos los datos de esas 2 tablas tendrais que hacer lo siguiente:

```
Select A.Id,
       A.Campo2,
       A.Campo3,
       B.Campo1,
       B.Campo2 
From ot_Ploteo AS AInner Join (Select Id,Campo2,Campo3,CampoN 
                               From ot_servicio_tecnico ) AS  B on(A.Id = 
                               B.Id)
```

- Acostumbrate no usar **`* from`**, siempre usa el **`select`** con los campos que necesitas y asigna un alias a cada tabla

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me ayudo mucho

Answer (score 1):

Amigo te dejo un ejemplo.

```
        select em.id_empresa, em.nombre_e, em.base from empresa_user eu 
        join usuarios us on eu.usuario = us.id_ususario join empresa em on 
        eu.id_empresa = em.id_empresa where us.nombre like 'VARIABLE'  order by 
        em.nombre_e;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me ayudo mucho

Answer (score 1):

La consulta es grande y las tablas tienen muchos campos, tal vez esto te sirva, aunque lo mejor fuera que definieras un borrador con la salida que deseas que genere la consulta. Si defines la salida deseada, podría ayudarte mejor.

```
SELECT * from cliente cst 
INNER JOIN ot_servicio_tecnico ON otst.ID_Cliente = cst.ID_Cliente
INNER JOIN ot_ploteo otp ON otp.ID_Cliente = cst.ID_Cliente 
INNER JOIN tipo_documento ON tdp.ID_Documento =  otp.ID_Documento 
GROUP BY cst.ID_Cliente;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me ayudo mucho

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 AS T1
INNER JOIN tbl2 T2 ON T1.Key = T2.Key
INNER JOIN tbl3 T3 ON T1.Key = T3.Key
```

Significa qué, buscarás todas las relaciones que existan entre T1 y T2, y T1 y T3, por lo que si una relación no existen en uno de los dos casos, podría no traerte un valor, mientras que si encuentras una relación entre ambos, podría traerte valors indeseados, lo que te hace falta sería agregar un valor de filtro extra en T3.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 AS T1
INNER JOIN tbl2 T2 ON T1.Key = T2.Key 
INNER JOIN tbl3 T3 ON T1.Key = T3.Key AND T2.Key = T3.Key
```

Con lo cual delimitarías las apariciones de T2 a las relaciones existentes además con T3

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me ayudo mucho